# Simple question: "Raw uint16 IR image" meaning?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there
my question is very simple, what does it mean: "Raw uint16 IR image" ?
(it's topic's data information: /camera/ir/image_raw)

and what should I put at rgb8 place when subscribing to that topic :

```
cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::rgb8);
```

Thank you so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/175196/simple-question:-%22raw-uint16-ir-image%22-meaning-?/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2014-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would mean that image has only a single unsigned 16-bit value per pixel. The actual meaning of that 16-bit value would be driver specific.

For cv_bridge, you probably want sensor_msgs::image::encodings::TYPE_16UC1 which would be a single channel of 16-bit values.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1